# NSNotificationCenter as the main events dispatcher across the app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Is it correct to use `NSNotificationCenter` as the only handler for all the events inside the app?

Is it fine if I put a list of all possible events like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loginUser:", name: "userWillLogin", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showError:", name: "userLoginError", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loadMainScreen:", name: "userDidLogin", object: nil)
    // Is it ok if I put 10 or 20 more event listeners here?

}
```

Or is the intention of this functionality different? I find it appealing to use event listeners and handlers in this manner, but not sure if it's the recommended way to pass events and data across the app regarding performance and best practices.

Answer (score 0):

When using only notifications you'll find yourself in troubles to debug what happened that something is broken. Notifications make tracking down bugs hard, because not always it's obvious what was the flow. There are situations when you should use them, but don't do it always via notifications - it's less readable.

The best way would be to use `delegate` pattern / `blocks` for 1:1 relationships and `NSNotificationCenter` / `KVO` for  1:n relationships.

Check out this link: http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/